# iPhone notification the first time app is launched

Tags: iphone, notifications, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm wanting the user to accept an agreement before the application is launched. So in the appDelegate.m I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(![defaults boolForKey:@"warningAccepted"]){
        UIAlertView *alert;
        alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Message... To continue, select \"OK\". To close the app, select \"Cancel\"." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"warningAccepted"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [window addSubview:mainNavController.view];
        } else {
            [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
        }

        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else {
        // Close App, User hit cancel.
        UIAlertView *alert;
        alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Cannot Continue" message:@"The application cannot run until warning is accepted." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

One problem is that the else never gets called when the user hits cancel. The other problem is that I'm not sure how to stop the app from continuing. From what I have found, Apple does not want you to force the application to close. Is that correct? How should I go about implementing this? Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Apple will reject your application if you force to exit. I can tell ;-) Another UIAlertView saying that the user cannot continue without accepting should de the trick (Just don't put any button on it so the user can't dismiss it)

About the else scope, does it not pass through it, or the UIAlertView doesn't show ? Check it with a breakpoint. Further more, isn't when `(buttonIndex == 0)` means that the user touched the "Cancel" button

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are correct, the cancel button is at index 0. If I just show another alertView (with no buttons) if the user hits cancel, will Apple accept it?

Comment: I'm going to guess that Apple would frown an on app that is useless without accepting certain terms.

Comment: What about the +17 rated apps and even some web browsers. They force the user to accept the terms. That is in essence what I am going for.

Comment: you can still do a loop : show the agreement -> if the user doesn't accept it show an view saying that they need to accept the agreement (with an ok button) -> if the user touch "ok" -> go back to show the agreement, and all over again. On the popup saying "you need to accept the agreement" specifies that if they do not accept, they should close the App by themselves...

Answer (score 2):

I have had success using this delegate method instead:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

And make sure that your application uses the cancelButtonIndex and firstOtherButtonIndex properties of the alertView so that you process the correct button; I think the cancel button is usually index zero at the moment but this could potentially change.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to handle an EULA is to submit it when you submit the application to iTunes.  This allows an end user to read the EULA prior to downloading your application.

If you want to force the user to accept an EULA prior to using the application, you should probably put the agreement into an HTML file which you can embed within the application.  Display the HTML in a UIWebView when your app starts up.  (Just a few lines of code.)  Do not try to squeeze it into an alert.

You are not allowed to "exit" the application.  You may wish to present the EULA in a webview with "Accept" and "Decline" options in a toolbar or as buttons on the webpage.  If the user selects "Decline", then you may pop an alert asking then to delete the app from their device.  The idea is they can scroll around the webview, but not continue until they hit accept.

I'm not sure if Apple will allow this, it will certainly frustrate your end users.

Comment: They allow it; there are a number of apps which do this already, such as Soft Pauer's F1 timing app.

Answer (score 0):

for problem number two: yes Apple does not want to quit the app. But what you can do to force the user to quit the app on his own: simply show a blank screen. But I'm not sure if Apple would even this allow because it could be seen as "no functionality".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I could create a another screen after the user hits cancel that simply waits until they hit OK. But do you have any idea why my second alert won't show up when I hit cancel?